# benchmark command is failing

Tags: 14.04, server, benchmarks

I built this benchmarks framework:
https://github.com/cksystemsgroup/scal

I followed the instructions and this is how the directory where I built it looks:

```
     AUTHORS                                   prodcon-bs-kfifo.target.mk                        seqalt-dds-1random-ms.target.mk
        autogen.sh                                prodcon-cts-queue.target.mk                       seqalt-dds-1random-treiber.target.mk
        bs-kfifo.target.mk                        prodcon-dds-1random-ms.target.mk                  seqalt-dds-partrr-ms.target.mk
        build                                     prodcon-dds-1random-treiber.target.mk             seqalt-dds-partrr-treiber.target.mk
        common.gypi                               prodcon-dds-partrr-ms.target.mk                   seqalt-eb-stack.target.mk
        computational-load.target.mk              prodcon-dds-partrr-treiber.target.mk              seqalt-fc.target.mk
        configure.ac                              prodcon-eb-stack.target.mk                        seqalt-hc-ts-atomic-queue.target.mk
        cts-queue.target.mk                       prodcon-fc.target.mk                              seqalt-hc-ts-atomic-stack.target.mk
        data                                      prodcon-hc-ts-atomic-queue.target.mk              seqalt-hc-ts-cas-queue.target.mk
        dds-1random-ms.target.mk                  prodcon-hc-ts-atomic-stack.target.mk              seqalt-hc-ts-cas-stack.target.mk
        seqalt-hc-ts-hardware-queue.target.mk
        seqalt-hc-ts-interval-queue.target.mk
        eb-stack.target.mk                        
        fc.target.mk glue.gyp                            
    glue.Makefile                             prodcon-hc-ts-stutter-queue.target.mk             seqalt-kstack.target.mk
        hc-ts-atomic-queue.target.mk              prodcon-hc-ts-stutter-stack.target.mk             seqalt-lb-queue.target.mk
        hc-ts-atomic-stack.target.mk              prodcon-kstack.target.mk                          seqalt-lb-stack.target.mk
        hc-ts-cas-queue.target.mk                 prodcon-lb-queue.target.mk                        seqalt-lcrq.target.mk
        hc-ts-cas-stack.target.mk                 prodcon-lb-stack.target.mk                        seqalt-ll-dds-ms.target.mk
        hc-ts-hardware-queue.target.mk            prodcon-lcrq.target.mk                            seqalt-ll-dds-treiber.target.mk
        hc-ts-hardware-stack.target.mk            prodcon-ll-dds-ms-nonlinempty.target.mk           seqalt-ll-dyn-dds-ms.target.mk
        hc-ts-interval-queue.target.mk            prodcon-ll-dds-ms.target.mk                       seqalt-ll-dyn-dds-treiber.target.mk
        hc-ts-interval-stack.target.mk            prodcon-ll-dds-treiber-nonlinempty.target.mk      seqalt-ll-kstack.target.mk
        hc-ts-stutter-queue.target.mk             prodcon-ll-dds-treiber.target.mk                  seqalt-ll-us-kfifo.target.mk
        hc-ts-stutter-stack.target.mk             prodcon-ll-dyn-dds-ms-nonlinempty.target.mk       seqalt-lru-dds-ms.target.mk
        kstack.target.mk                          prodcon-ll-dyn-dds-ms.target.mk                   seqalt-lru-dds-treiber-stack.target.mk
        lb-queue.target.mk                        prodcon-ll-dyn-dds-treiber-nonlinempty.target.mk  seqalt-ms.target.mk
        lb-stack.target.mk                        prodcon-ll-dyn-dds-treiber.target.mk              seqalt-rd.target.mk
        lcrq-base.target.mk                       prodcon-ll-kstack.target.mk                       seqalt-rts-queue.target.mk
        lcrq.target.mk                            prodcon-ll-us-kfifo.target.mk                     seqalt-sq.target.mk
        libscal.target.mk                         prodcon-lru-dds-ms.target.mk                      seqalt-treiber.target.mk
        LICENSE                                   prodcon-lru-dds-treiber-stack.target.mk           seqalt-ts-atomic-deque.target.mk
        ll-dds-ms-nonlinempty.target.mk           ****prodcon-ms.target.mk****                              seqalt-ts-cas-deque.target.mk
seqalt-ts-interval-deque.target.mk
ll-dds-treiber.target.mk                  prodcon-sq.target.mk                              seqalt-ts-stutter-deque.target.mk
ll-dyn-dds-ms-nonlinempty.target.mk       prodcon-treiber.target.mk                         seqalt-us-kfifo.target.mk
ll-dyn-dds-ms.target.mk                   prodcon-ts-atomic-deque.target.mk                 sq.target.mk
        ll-dyn-dds-treiber-nonlinempty.target.mk  prodcon-ts-cas-deque.target.mk                    src
        ll-dyn-dds-treiber.target.mk              prodcon-ts-hardware-deque.target.mk               tools
        ll-kstack.target.mk                                      treiber.target.mk
        ll-us-kfifo.target.mk                     
        lru-dds-ms.target.mk                     
        lru-dds-treiber-stack.target.mk           rd.target.mk                                      
        Makefile                                  README.md                                         ts-interval-deque.target.mk
        Makefile.am                               rts-queue.target.mk                               ts-stutter-deque.target.mk
        mm-harness.target.mk                      scal.gyp                                          upstream.gyp
        ms.target.mk                              scal.Makefile                                     upstream.Makefile
        out
```

they give examples on how to proceed with benchmarks as follow:

```
./prodcon-ms -producers=15 -consumers=15 -operations=100000 -c=250
```

the file  *prodcon-ms.target.mk* is among the files listed (i put stars around it for ease to read)

When I type the command as they specified I get:

```
-bash: ./prodcon-ms: No such file or directory
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `prodcon-ms` is meant to exist in the toplevel directory - rather than as `./out/Release/prodcon-ms` for example?

Comment: @steeldriver there are other files in out/release/  let me try those and report back

Comment: @steeldriver yes they work, although I get this warning which I assume it's becuase I am not root: `warning: unable to modify scheduler policy and priority for worker threads. consider running the benchmark with sufficient priviliges.` shall I just ignore it?